# Link Twitter Usernames in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

how can I mention anyone who is in  Twitter Usernames in WordPress? like @username  and it will reflect in my wordpress post and when someone click on it ,he can redirect to his Twitter account
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQHie.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use hyperlink on "@username" and have the URL be their Twitter profile link. Hyperlinks are usually the chain icons in the text editors.

Aside from the default Wordpress editor, you can also set it via HTML as follows:

```
<a href="https:/twitter.com/username">@username</a>
```

Comment: but i need an automated process -is there any plugin or code available ?

Comment: @debanjanmukherjee kindly see my edited answer above for the code example

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the Gutenberg block editor, you can convert any word to a link. So in your example, you would hightlight `@username` and convert that to a link which points to the Twitter URL. See https://prnt.sc/10mupqq for an example.